# Selenium Python | 'find_elements_by_class_name' returns nothing

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, dynamic

I am trying to scrape job titles from a dynamic job listing. When I use the function find_elements_by_class_name, the function doesn't return anything. I'm new to selenium so i'm not sure if i'm simply doing something incorrectly or misunderstanding the functionality.

The page im trying to scrape is: https://recruit.hirebridge.com/v3/CareerCenter/v2/?cid=7724

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

#define the path for the chrome webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:/web/jobListing/chromedriver.exe"

#create a instance of the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("https://recruit.hirebridge.com/v3/CareerCenter/v2/?cid=7724")
time.sleep(10)
jobs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("col-md-8 jobtitle")

print("starting print")
for job in jobs:
    print(job.text)
```

Comment: use `find_elements_by_class_name("jobtitle")`

Comment: Simply you have to replace the spaces between class names with `.`, find more explanation in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Root Cause:**

`col-md-8` and `jobtitle` are 2 different classes. When you use `find_element_by_class_name` it will internally convert the class name to a css selector and try to find the element.

Below is the evidence where `find_element_by_class_name` uses the `css` internally.

[image]

**Solution:**

As Selenium internally uses the `css` you have to make sure the classes are clubbed together meaning `class1.class2.class3`. In simple terms `replace all white spaces with single dot` in the class name from UI.

**How to implement this to your situation:**

You have to use the below syntax.

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('col-md-8.jobtitle')
```

Comment: This will work, but only because the webdriver add `.` to the expression internally [line 1006](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py). The uses is `find_element_by_class_name('col-md-8')` or `find_element_by_class_name('jobtitle')`, or for multiple classes use `css_selector` directly with `'.col-md-8.jobtitle'`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
jobs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-md-8 jobtitle']/a")
```

I've switched the find element by class for xpath, this way you have more flexibility and it generally works better, I suggest you look into it!

Comment: I prefer `find_elements_by_css_selector` which works regardless of the order of the class names, e.g., `find_elements_by_css_selector('div.jobtitle.col-md-8')`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug?
This works:

```
jobs = driver.execute_script("""
  return document.getElementsByClassName("col-md-8 jobtitle")
""")
```