# python selenium find_elements_by_class_name not returning as expected, works for 1st page but not next one

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some data as below, the website has 3 pages I want to scrape, it works for the first page but not the other ones even though the class name is the same on the website!!

```
def getdata(link):
  qtexts=[]
  answers=[]
  browser.get(link)
  q=browser.find_elements_by_class_name("nova-v-question-item__title")
  for x in q:
    qtexts.append(x.text)
  r=browser.find_elements_by_class_name("nova-v-message-contribution-item")
  for y in r:
    answers.append(y.text)
  df = pd.DataFrame({'answers':answers,'question':qtexts})
  return df

df1  = getdata('https://www.researchgate.net/topic/Electric-Vehicles')
```

.. this works

```
df2  = getdata('https://www.researchgate.net/topic/Electric-Vehicles/2')
```

.. this returns nothing!

I've looked at similar questions ([Selenium Python | 'find_elements_by_class_name' returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422998/selenium-python-find-elements-by-class-name-returns-nothing)) but can't find the solution...

Thank you in advance + all the best

Comment: That method is known to be buggy. use css_selector instead.

Comment: thanks, do i search for the same term? (nova-v-question-item__title)

Comment: with a dot in front: `'.nova-v-question-item__title'`